# AppleScript: Retrieve the path of the current project/workspace in Xcode

Tags: xcode, bash, applescript

## Short version

Using AppleScript I want to retrieve the path of the current project/workspace in Xcode. How do I do this?

## Long version

I want to create an Xcode behaviour that shows me a diff between the current branch and the default branch. My plan for doing this is:

1. Use AppleScript to get the path of the current project/workspace
2. Pass the path to bash script which:

   - Determines the default git branch
   - Runs `git difftool {DEFAULT_BRANCH}`

I'm stuck on step 1.

(I've been programming for over 20 years and I still can't figure out AppleScript.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward

```
tell application "Xcode"
    set currentWorkspacePath to path of active workspace document
end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up with:

```
#! /bin/bash

WORKSPACE_PATH=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Xcode"
    set workspacePath to path of active workspace document
end tell')

source ~/.bash_profile
cd "$WORKSPACE_PATH/.."
GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH=$(git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | sed 's@^refs/remotes/origin/@@')
git difftool "$GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
```

Many thanks @vadian